# Is JDBC connectino url setting's priority higher than database server setting?

Tags: java, mysql, database

In my project, I stored LocalDateTime field by using JPA.

That field is stored as UTC But I wanted Asia/Seoul(UTC+9)

So I changed mysql server timezone GLOBAL and SESSION setting to Asia/Seoul But still LocalDateTime fields stored UTC based.

When I'm debugging, I'm noticed. JDBC connection url's serverTimezone setting is UTC.

That's my JDBC connection url

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/roommanager?character_set_server=utf-8&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Here, I wonder it

Why JDBC connection url setting's priority higher thatn database server setting?

If you know that, I want to read the official document about that.

My project database & version : mysql 5.6

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about priority as I understand it but about conversion, by setting a time zone in your jdbc connection string all dates will be converted to that timezone. If you want the time zone used in the database then remove the setting from your connection string (or apply the wanted timezone).

Comment: Is server setting replaced by connection string ?